# How to get IOS device "its own" Bluetooth UUID pragmatically?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, uuid

I am developing an application that requires the ios device to provide its own Bluetooth UUID (not get the Bluetooth UUID from scanned/connected device), then send it to the server for further development. I can not find any answer on the internet.

Question:

1. How to get ios device "its own" bluetooth uuid pragmatically? (It is not another device's bluetooth uuid and it is not another device that connected to my device, then find my bluetooth uuid. It is the device own bluetooth uuid and get it without any connection to another device.)
2. Is the bluetooth uuid unique? It seem that the bluetooth uuid will be changed every 15 mins, how to detect the uuid is changed? Can I set the custom Bluetooth uuid?

Answer (score -1):

**Objective-C**

`NSString *newUUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];`

---

**EDIT**

iOS Bluetooth technology contains two main entities for you to concern yourself with; *Centrals* and *Peripherals*. *Centrals* are devices that desire data, and *Peripherals* are devices that deliver the data. When you send data from a *Peripheral* to a *Central*, the *Central* will be observing the `CBService`s and `CBCharacteristic`s that a *Peripheral* will be trying to send to the *Central*.

[image]

To answer your question: the `UUID` you want to check for should not be associated with a device, it should be assocated with your `CBService`s and `CBPeripheral`s.

`CBUUID *myService = [CBUUID UUIDWithString: @"MyServiceID"];`

If you want **must** keep track of devices I suppose one thing you could do is the following:

**SENDING**

```
// Get Device ID
NSString *deviceID = [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString;

// Add To Serivce ID With Space Inbetween
NSString *newID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", myServiceID, deviceID];
```

**RECEIVING**

```
// Then When You Read It, Splice at the "Space"
NSArray *splice = [newID componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

// Device
NSString *readDeviceID = splice[0];

// Service ID
NSString *readServiceID = splice[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is only generate a new uuid. I want to know is  that the Bluetooth send some information to the air which contains the uuid. How can I get that id programmatically without any connection between another iOS device?